# replacing values in selected columns of a dataframe using RegExp

Tags: regex, r, replace, dataframe

Assume I have a dataframe

```
mydata <- c("10 stack"," 10 stack and x" , "10 stack / dd" ," 10 stackxx")
R>mydata
[1] " 10 stack"
[2] " 10 stack and x" 
[3] " 10 stack  / dd"   
[4] " 10 stackxx"
```

what I want to do is **to replace and word begin with 10** stack [anything]to any other words in the dataframe , but without removing the rest of the string 
the desired output. **Also replace the backslash with and or comma.**

```
[1] " new"
[2] " new and x" 
[3] " new  and dd"   
[4] " new"
```

my code is

```
mydata[mydata =="10 stack" ] <- new # I can replace one type, but I need faster operation.
mydata[mydata =="///" ] <- and #for replacing backslash with and
```

I found another method can solve the problem

```
mydata<-as.data.frame(sapply(mydata,gsub,pattern="//\",replacement=","))
```

Comment: do you want to replace `10 stackxx` with `new`?

Comment: yes, any word begin with 10. I want to replace it with "new", but if there is another word in the dataframe I want to keep it.

Comment: do you want to replace `10` with `new` or `10 stack[anything]` with `new`

Comment: 10 stack[anything] with new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
library(stringi) 
stri_replace_all_regex(mydata, c("10 stack", "\\/"), c("new", "and"), vectorize_all=FALSE)
```

Which gives:

```
#[1] "new"        " new and x" "new and dd" " newxx"
```

---

As per mentioned by @rock321987 in the comments, if you want to replace `10 stack[anything]`, You could use the pattern `\\b10 stack[^\\s]*` instead:

```
stri_replace_all_regex(mydata, c("\\b10 stack[^\\s]*", "\\/"), c("new", "and"), 
                       vectorize_all=FALSE)
```

Which gives:

```
#[1] "new"        " new and x" "new and dd" " new"
```

Comment: This is fast answer , but still if I want to replace 10 stack[anything]. in other words any string begins with 10.

Comment: @Maged `stri_replace_all_regex(mydata, c("\\b10 stack[^\\s]*", "\\/"), c("new", "and"), vectorize_all=FALSE)`

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me, "10 stack[anything]" is *a lot* different from "any string that begins with 10". You mean "10" and the word following ? All words following "10" (in which case you would also replace "and x") ? "All words following "10" that are not "\" or "and" or ","...

Comment: sorry if it is not being cleared form the beginning. in the data I have, the word stack could be stackx, stackk, or anything like that. so from the beginning I want to replace 10 stack[anything], but keep the remaining dataframe.

Comment: @Maged Then the update should satisfy your requirement.

Comment: yes thank you both, but I wonder what is the meaning of "b" before 10 ?

Comment: @Maged: The metacharacter `\\b` is an anchor like the caret and the dollar sign. It matches at a position that is called a "word boundary". This match is zero-length. http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to use sub() function, which matches pattern and substitute it with replacement.

```
sub("10 stack", " new", mydata)
```

Comment: it solves the problem partially, I need to replce 10 stack[anything] not 10 stack. in other words any string begins with "10".

Comment: then try sub("^10", "new", mydata)

Comment: it should work, but I don't know for some reasons the data won't replaced.

Comment: after your explaination in the other thread I think it may look like this:

sub("^10 stack[a-zA-Z]*", " new", mydata)